# Don't understand why this number is undefined, and why another value is null

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to create a simple little daily rewards system with a JSON database to store the rewards and time left before receiving them. Here's my code:

```
   var user = message.author.id;
   var userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./Toasty/users.json', 'utf8'));

   var breadcrumbsRandom = breadcrumbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * breadcrumbs.length)];
   var breadRandom = bread[Math.floor(Math.random() * bread.length)];
   var toastRandom = toast[Math.floor(Math.random() * toast.length)];
   var toastersRandom = toasters[Math.floor(Math.random() * toasters.length)];

   message.channel.sendMessage(`**${message.author.username}**, you have received the daily rewards of **${breadcrumbsRandom}** breadcrumbs, **${breadRandom}** slices of bread, **${toastRandom}** pieces of toast and **${toastersRandom}** toasters!`);

   var breadcrumbsInt = parseInt(breadcrumbsRandom);
   var breadInt = parseInt(breadRandom);
   var toastInt = parseInt(toastRandom);
   var toastersInt = parseInt(toastersRandom);

   if (!userData[user]) userData[user] = {
       "breadcrumbs": 0,
       "bread": 0,
       "toast": 0,
       "toasters": 0
   };

   console.log(userData[user].breadcrumbs);
   console.log(breadcrumbsInt);

   userData[user].breadcrumbs = userData[user].breadcrumbs + breadcrumbsInt;
   userData[user].bread = userData[user].bread + breadInt;
   userData[user].toast = userData[user].toast + toastInt;
   userData[user].toasters = userData[user].toasters + toastersInt;
   var updateRewards = JSON.stringify(userData, null, 2);
   fs.writeFile('./Toasty/users.json', updateRewards);
```

The problem is that userData[user].breadcrumbs is undefined when I log it, and so would be .bread .toast and .toasters be if I logged those values. I don't understand why it's undefined. Also when use writeFile and I check what the .json file has, it says null for the breadcrumbs, bread, toast and toasters values. Thanks in advance for your help and time!

Comment: It is look like if `breadcrumbsInt` is `null`: check it.

Comment: breadcrumbsInt is fine, userData[user].breadcrumbs is undefined @stdob--